# How to throttle ServiceStack Messaging EventHandler

Tags: servicestack, rabbitmq

I know this sounds like an anti-pattern, but I have a requirement that dictates that the flow of messages to a service (Cisco phones) be configurable i.e. throttling.

There will be times when our phone system can not handle the load of the messages being routed to it from ServiceStack via RabbitMQ Broker (work queue), it's during these peak times that I need to curb the flow of the messages. I've read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19163021) SO QA, but don't know if that's applicable or not. Should I just Nak the messages based on some throttling algorithm in the client handler?

Thank you, Stephen

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default there is only 1 worker thread (per message type) that's used to process the request, so you can just add a `Thread.Sleep()` in your Service to delay processing of the request as the next request only gets processed after the previous one has finished.

Comment: Got it, although I've started out with 4 threads for all my handlers :), maybe a was a bit optimistic about the throughput. When we cross this bridge again it will mean that we were very successful with our implementation