# How to consume one message?

Tags: java, rabbitmq

With [example](http://www.rabbitmq.com/tutorials/tutorial-one-java.html) in rabbitmq, consumer get all messages from queue at one time. How to consume one message and exit?

```
QueueingConsumer consumer = new QueueingConsumer(channel);
channel.basicConsume(QUEUE_NAME, true, consumer);

while (true) {
  QueueingConsumer.Delivery delivery = consumer.nextDelivery();
  String message = new String(delivery.getBody());
  System.out.println(" [x] Received '" + message + "'");
}
```

Comment: if not use a loop, all messages lost except one.

Comment: Isn't that what you wanted? Consume one message and exit.

Comment: QueueingConsumer.Delivery delivery = consumer.nextDelivery(); read all messages from queue at one time

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19163021/rabbitmq-how-to-throttle-the-consumer

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You have to declare basicQos setting to get one message at a time from ACK to NACK status and disable auto ACK to give acknowledgement explicitly.

```
ConnectionFactory factory = new ConnectionFactory();
    factory.setHost("localhost");
    Connection connection = factory.newConnection();
    Channel channel = connection.createChannel();
    channel.basicQos(1);
    channel.queueDeclare(QUEUE_NAME, true, false, false, null);
    System.out.println("[*] waiting for messages. To exit press CTRL+C");

    QueueingConsumer consumer = new QueueingConsumer(channel);
    channel.basicConsume(QUEUE_NAME, consumer);
    while(true) {
        QueueingConsumer.Delivery delivery = consumer.nextDelivery();
        int n = channel.queueDeclarePassive(QUEUE_NAME).getMessageCount();
        System.out.println(n);
        if(delivery != null) {
            byte[] bs = delivery.getBody();
            System.out.println(new String(bs));
            //String message= new String(delivery.getBody());
            channel.basicAck(delivery.getEnvelope().getDeliveryTag(), false);
            //System.out.println("[x] Received '"+message);
        }
    }
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: Also, as a word of caution to the OP: RabbitMQ team does not recommend reading only one at a time. Reason: http://www.rabbitmq.com/blog/2011/09/24/sizing-your-rabbits/

Comment: I don't think setting BasicQOS to 1 solves it. "This is done by setting a "prefetch count" value using the basic.qos method. The value defines the max number of unacknowledged deliveries that are permitted on a channel. Once the number reaches the configured count, RabbitMQ will stop delivering more messages on the channel unless at least one of the outstanding ones is acknowledged. ". From http://www.rabbitmq.com/confirms.html

Answer (score 1):

Use AMQP 0.9.1 [basic.get](http://www.rabbitmq.com/amqp-0-9-1-quickref.html) to synchronously get just one message.

```
ConnectionFactory factory = new ConnectionFactory();
factory.setUri(uri);

Connection connection = factory.newConnection();
Channel channel = connection.createChannel();

channel.queueDeclare(QUEUE_NAME, true, false, false, null);

GetResponse response = channel.basicGet(QUEUE_NAME, true);
if (response != null) {
    String message = new String(response.getBody(), "UTF-8");
}

channel.close();
connection.close();
```

Comment: Perfect, exactly what I was looking for for a quick integration test.

Answer (score 0):

```
const consumeFromQueue = async (queueName) => {
    try {

        let data = await channel.get(queueName)// get one msg at a time
        if (data) {

            data.content ? eval("(" + data.content.toString() + ")()") : ""
            channel.ack(data)
        } else {
            //console.log("Empty Queue")
        }
    }
    catch (error) {
        //console.log("Error while consuming from rabbitmq queue", error)
        return Promise.reject(error)
    }
}
```

Comment: That isn't Java, the question was tagged as Java.