# Horizontal scaling of consumers when the publisher provides sequenced messages

Tags: asynchronous, rabbitmq, microservices

In a distributed service oriented architecture, lets say I have a producer that send messages to a consumer using RMQ.

We decided then to horizontally scale the consuming part of our architecture by adding more consumers and we faced some limitations.

The publisher provide a sequence number in every message it sent. And it’s very important that the consumers process the messages based on the sequence number it has.

Every time that deal with a given resource, lets say A, the publisher will send RMQ messages that says "Hey lets do sequence 1 for A" and then "Hey lets do sequence 2 for A" and so on.

If for example the publisher provides 3 messages for A with sequences 1, 2 and 3 and the 3 messages are distributed to 3 different instances of our consumer. The message of sequence 2 is requeued until sequence 1 is well processed, same for sequence 3.

At the end the messages are all well processed, but after many retries! This causes some latency in our system as we retries many times if we’ve 100 sequences to consume.

A possible solution would be to make sure each set of sequences for a given resource has to be processed by the same consumer. But how can we achieve that?

How can I avoid the requeuing in order to make sure every instance of our consumer always get the messages for a given resource well ordered?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try the following:

- Create a `topic exchange`
- Make your producer to send messages to it
  with topic per resource: topic `A` for resource `A`, topic `B` for
  resource `B` and so on.
- Make 1 consumer to listen to 1 topic. Use durable queue for each
  consumer, so the queue will survive consumer restarts. If you have
  producer -> one exchange -> 1 queue -> 1 consumer message path, the
  order of messages is guaranteed, see [RabbitMQ broker semantics](https://www.rabbitmq.com/semantics.html)
  for details.
- Make your consumer to get [1 message at a time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29841690/how-to-consume-one-message), and `ack` it only when
  processing is done.

This will hopefully give you sequential processing that you need and you don't need to re-queue messages.

Note that there is a possibility of receiving the same message twice - if your consumer died in between finishing processing task and `acking` the message.

Comment: This is probably the closest OP is going to get to the implementation in question, but there will be more needed to make the solution resilient against data loss and "dead-ending" data.  (Ask what would happen if a queue consumer crashes and see what the solution does.)  OP might consider that RabbitMQ is either the wrong tool or the solution will require other tools in addition to RabbitMQ.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with RMQ but I'll try to help.

For me it seems that you want to scale your consumers in a way that each consumer is dedicated for a single resource. This is necessary as you have dependency between the sequences for a single resource, thus there is no point distributing the work between multiple consumers.

I have experience with Kafka and there you can use so called "topics" to send messages to and have a consumer dedicated for a single topic which grabs the work items from there.

Not sure if this is possible on RMQ though.

If this is not an option on your architecture, I'd try the following:
Dedicate a single consumer for a resource by checking the message payload first whether it is relevant for that resource. If yes then execute the work, if not then requeue it.

Answer (score 0):

RabbitMQ is just a broker to route messages. You should not use it to manage your business because you will have a lots of complicated routing rules.

I personally solved this issue with a single consumer. Its goal is to listen on a queue, push events in a stack depending on a business rule. If you still need to scale up the number of consumer you can use reactive architecture pattern which let's you orchestrate the load balancing between all forked instances.

Another solution using RabbitMQ is to set the priority of the message and create consumer listening on specific priority. https://www.rabbitmq.com/priority.html

If this two solutions still not fix your problem, you can set a queue by consumer and send the sequence in the corresponding queue when you requeue the message. With this simple solution, you will always be sure that a given message is read by the same consumer but you'll loose the benefits of the load balancing.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you want your messages to be partitioned by resource id.

There is a plugin for that: https://github.com/rabbitmq/rabbitmq-sharding
It will partition a queue into a number of shards by applying consistent hashing to the message routing key. This is done via [Consistent Hash Exchange](https://github.com/rabbitmq/rabbitmq-consistent-hash-exchange) as I understand.

[image: sharded queues picture]

You can use your resource id as a routing key, so **messages for the same resource will end up in the same shard.** Each consumer will be handling messages from one shard and they should be coming in the publishing order. So you should see messages for the same resource coming in order.